# A question about proof of Martingale Convergence Theorem. Why does the Uniform integrability imply the following fact?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, martingales, lipschitz-functions, uniform-integrability

Relying on the below definition of *uniform integrability*:

> ***Definition***: A subset $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathcal{L}^{1}$ is said to be a *uniformly integrable* collection of random variables if 
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim\limits_{c\rightarrow\infty}\sup\limits_{X\in\mathcal{U}}\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\geq c\}}|X|\}=0
> \end{equation}

I have to prove the following statement (***Martingale Convergence Theorem***):

> Let $(M_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a martingale and suppose $(M_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a uniformly integrable collection of random variables. Then:
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_n=M_{\infty} \hspace{0.5cm} \text{exists a.s.}
> \end{equation}
>   $M_{\infty}$ is in $\mathcal{L}^1$ and $M_n$ converges to $M_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$

---

After proving that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_n=M_{\infty}$ exists a.s. and $M_{\infty}$ is in $\mathcal{L}^1$, I would like to prove that $M_n$ converges to $M_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$, that is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{|M_n - M_{\infty}|^{1}|\}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{|M_n - M_{\infty}|\}=0$.

On **JACOD-PROTTER** I read:

> To show that $M_n$ converges to $M_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$, define
>   \begin{equation}
> f_c (x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \hspace{0.3cm}c & \text{if} & x>c\\
> \hspace{0.3cm}x & \text{if} & |x|\leq c\\
> -c & \text{if} & x < -c 
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   Then, $f$ is Lipschitz (*that is, there exists a real constant $c\geq0$ s.t. $\forall x_1$, $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}\hspace{0.3cm} |f_c(x_1)-f_c(x_2)| \leq c|x_1-x_2|$*).
>    **BY THE UNIFORM INTEGRABILITY, THERE EXISTS $c$ SUFFICIENTLY LARGE THAT FOR $\epsilon>0$ GIVEN, IT HOLDS THAT:**
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}\{|f_c(M_n)-M_n|\}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\text{,}\hspace{0.3cm} \text{all} \hspace{0.1cm} n\text{;}
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}\{|f_c(M_{\infty})-M_{\infty}|\}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}
> \end{equation}
>   Since $\lim M_n = M_{\infty}$ a.s., we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_c(M_n)=f_c(M_{\infty})$, so by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, for $n\geq N$ ($N$ large enough):
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}\{|f_c(M_n)-f_c(M_{\infty})|\}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}
> \end{equation}
>   **THEREFORE, USING THE THREE ABOVE INEQUALITIES, ONE GETS:**
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}\{|M_n-M_{\infty}|\}<\epsilon\text{,}\hspace{0.2cm}\text{for}\hspace{0.1cm} n\geq N
> \end{equation}
>   which is equivalent to stating that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{|M_n-M_{\infty}|\}=0$, that is $M_n\rightarrow M_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$.
>
> $\blacksquare$

There are two points I cannot clearly understand in JACOD-PROTTER quoted proof part:

- **(FIRST PART IN BOLD CAPITAL LETTERS)**: Why do the first two inequalities follow from application of uniform integrability of $M_n$? I thought that they were just a consequence of the above defined Lipschitz function $f_c(x)$, such that, for a sufficiently large $c$, $f_c(M_n)=M_n$ and $f_c(M_{\infty})=M_{\infty}$. So, why are the first two inequalities a consequence of uniform integrability nature of $M_n$ and how the Lipsich function $f_c(x)$ is involved in the application of the definition of uniform integrability of a subset (defined above as well, at the beginning), which is $(M_n)$ in our case?;
- **(SECOND PART IN BOLD CAPITAL LETTERS)**: Why if I sum both sides of the first three inequalities above, on l.h.s. I get $\mathbb{E}\{|M_n-M_{\infty}|\}$, that is why $\mathbb{E}\{|f_c(M_n)-M_n|\}+\mathbb{E}\{|f_c(M_{\infty})-M_{\infty}|\}+\mathbb{E}\{|f_c(M_n)-f_c(M_{\infty})|\}=\mathbb{E}\{|M_n-M_{\infty}|\}$?.

Comment: For your second question, it is just the triangle inequality $$\mathbb{E}\{|M_n-M_{\infty}|\}\leq \mathbb{E}\{|M_n-f_c(M_n)|\}+\mathbb{E}\{|f_c(M_{\infty})-M_{\infty}|\}+\mathbb{E}\{|f_c(M_n)-f_c(M_{\infty})|\}<\epsilon$$

Comment: Yes, I got it now, thank you a lot for clarifying the second part! Do you have a clue about the first part as well? @Tab1e

Comment: I think you are right on "for a sufficiently large $c$, $f_c(M_n)=M_n$ and $f_c(M_{\infty})=M_{\infty}$." The uniformly integrability of $M_n$ basically allows such $M_n$ and $M_\infty$ to be defined within the domain $|x|\leq c$ of $f_c$ for $c$ sufficiently large.

Comment: I don't want to answer the first question because I am not sure about the relationship between Lipschitz continuity and uniformly integrability. But the experiences in real analysis told me that it may be the case.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re your 1st question (since the 2nd question has been already answered):

By definition, we have $f_c(x)=x$ for all $|x| \leq c$ and $f_c(x)=\pm c$ for $|x| > c$. Thus, $$|f_c(x)-x| \leq (|x|+c) 1_{|x| > c} \leq 2|x| 1_{|x| >c}.$$ Using this identity for $x=M_n(\omega)$ gives $$|f_c(M_n)-M_n| \leq 2|M_n| 1_{|M_n|>c}.$$ Taking expectation we find that $$\mathbb{E}(|f_c(M_n)-M_n|) \leq 2  \mathbb{E}(|M_n| 1_{|M_n|>c}).$$ Since $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable, the right-hand side is smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ (uniformly in $n$) for some sufficiently large constant $c=c(\epsilon)$. For $M_{\infty}$ we can use the same reasoning (recalling that $\{X\}$ is uniformly integrable for any $X \in L^1$).

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot for replying. Two doubts about your answer: FIRST, isn't true that $f_c(x)=|c|$ for $|x|>c$ and so, for $x=M_n(\omega)$, $|f_c(M_n)-M_n|=|c-M_n|1_{\{|M_n|>c\}}$? SECONDLY, how is $\mathbb{E}(|f_c(M_n)-M_n|)$ related to the definition of uniform integrability that I have provided in my question? @saz

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Sorry; fixed it; should be fine now.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and help, so grateful, I got it now! :) @saz

Comment: @Strictly_increasing You are welcome.